# Find Single Quote in Array (JS, jQuery or PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

First, sorry for my bad english ;)

I have a Array like this:

```
["47'", "", "Messi", "L."]
```

*(Output from .split(" "))*

Sometime its:

```
["Messi", "L.", "", "47'"]
```

Now I need to find the time (by '), Name and Lastname but I have no idea how could I get the time (once I get the position of time I know the position of the other).
My programming skills are not the best, I mostly use code snippets I found and try to understand and learn from them.

For better understanding: I loop over this

```
<tr class="score_row">
    <td class="home">47'  <span class="slball"></span>Messi L.</td>
    <td class="away">Ronaldo C.<span="yellowcard"></span> 68'</td>
</tr>
<tr class="score_row"> ... </tr>
```

and want to put it in a JSON Array

```
{"lastname":"Messi","name":"L.","time":"47","type":"slball"}
```

This will be send via AJAX to PHP.

I hope you understand my problem even if I don't find the right words to describe my problem.

EDIT:
My Code so far

```js
<?php echo "var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()}, ".$CONFIG['LOTTETICKER']['TIME'].");" ?>

function myTimer() {
    createJSON();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'content/liveticker.include.php',
        data: {'goals': jsonString},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#wrapper").html(data);
        }
    });
}

myTimer();

function createJSON() {
jsonObj = [];
    $("#live .spiel").each(function() {

        var result = $(".score_t", this).text().replace(/\s+/g, '').split(":");

        item = {}

        item ["home"] = result[0];
        item ["away"] = result[1];
        item ["homeid"] = $(".heim_hidden", this).text();
        item ["awayid"] = $(".gast_hidden", this).text();
        item ["gameid"] = $(".id_hidden", this).text();
        item ["goalcards"] = [];

        $(".score_row:not(.main) .home", this).add($(".score_row:not(.main) .away", this)).each(function() {
            goal = {}
            if ($(this).text() != "\xA0") {
                goal ["nametime"] = $(this).text().split(" "); //placeholder for Name, Lastname and Time
                goal ["typ"] = $("span", this).attr("class");

                item["goalcards"].push(goal);
            }
         });

        jsonObj.push(item);

    }); 
    jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    console.log(jsonString);
}
```

Output should be:

```
 [{"home":"1","away":"0","homeid":"18";"awayid":"6","gameid":"34","goalcards":[{"‌​lastname":"Messi","name":"L.","time":"47","type":"slball"},{"lastname":"Ronaldo",‌​"name":"C.","time":"68","type":"yellowcard"}]}]
```

Solution (I'm so dumb sometimes):

```
var nametime = $(this).text().split(" ");
if ($(this).attr("class") == "home") {
    goal ["firstname"] = nametime[2];
    goal ["lastname"] = nametime[3];
    goal ["time"] = nametime[0].slice(0,-1);
} else {
    goal ["firstname"] = nametime[0];
    goal ["lastname"] = nametime[1];
    goal ["time"] = nametime[3].slice(0,-1);
}
```

Comment: The ordering is based on whether that cell is marked as "home" or "away".

Comment: Yes, your right.
For mor better understanding. My Json should look like this at the end:
    [{"home":"1","away":"0","homeid":"18";"awayid":"6","gameid":"34","goalcards":[{"lastname":"Messi","name":"L.","time":"47","type":"slball"},{"lastname":"Ronaldo","name":"C.","time":"68","type":"yellowcard"}]}]

Comment: @Jack: Thanks!
Im so dumb sometimes ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over the strings in your array, you can check if `str.indexOf("'") > -1` it means that this string contains your single quote character.

Comment: to prevent matching the "'" in names as well (like in O'Reilly) it would be better to do: if( str.trim().indexOf("'") == str.length-1 )

Answer (score 0):

note : personally I would better look for a better source of the data ...

In JS I would do :

```
var GER_USA = ["Mueller", "T.", "", "02'"];
var pos = -1;
GER_USA.forEach(function(str, i){ 
    if( str.trim().indexOf("'") == str.length-1 ) pos=i; 
});

// we have a time and position if (pos>-1) ...
if (pos>-1) {
    var time = parseInt( GER_USA[pos].replace("'","") );
    // var topscorer = GER_USA[pos-3];
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T85D3/)